# Help With Creating Shortcode

Tags: functions, shortcode

I'm looking for a way to check just check for an option existing when executing a shortcode, but that option doesnt need a value. How do I just check for JUST an option? For example I tried this out, I want the following code to output true, but it is still outputting false.

PHP:

```
function Test($atts) {
 extract(shortcode_atts(array(
  'row' => null
 ), $atts));
 $output = 'false';
 if($row) {
  $output = 'true';
 }
 return $output;
}
add_shortcode("test", "Test");
```

In The WYSIWYG:

```
[test row]
```

Will just output "false". But if I were to say:

```
[test row="true"]
```

It will output "true" onto the page.

Again, I want to just check for that option `row` just being there, not to have to feed it a value. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that extract() function sets it to false if value is not provided.
There might be a better way around it, but I've used workaround as follows

```
function Test($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
     'row' => null
    ), $atts));

    $output = 'false';
    if( in_array('row', $atts))
        $output = 'true';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode("test", "Test");
```